# Requirement of Jordan-Wigner string in creation operator on Fock state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, definition, fermions, grassmann-numbers

Our lecture notes described the action of the particle creation operator on a fermionic Fock state:

$$c_l^\dagger |n_1 n_2...\rangle = (-1)^{\sum_{j=1}^{l-1}n_j}|n_1 n_2 ... n_l+1 ...\rangle.$$

I am confused by why the $(-1)^{\sum_{j=1}^{l-1}n_j}$ factor is needed? Is it to maintain anti-symmetry of the wavefunction somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially yes. Recall the state for $ n_m=n_n=... =1$  with  all intermediate occupation numbers  vanishing,
$$  |n_1 n_2...\rangle = c_m^\dagger c_n^\dagger   ...|0\rangle.$$

If $\ell$ is one of the above occupied sites, $n_\ell=1$, nilpotence of the creation operators when $c_\ell^\dagger$ is applied on the state will net you 0, so you hardly care about about the phase multiplying it.

If not, then $n_\ell+1=1$, and, to get to that site, $c_\ell^\dagger$ has anticommuted with $c_ m^\dagger, c_n^\dagger, ...$ preceding it, to get to the $ \ell $ site, so it has picked up $\sum_{j=1}^{\ell-1}n_j$ minus signs, multiplying each other,
$$c_\ell^\dagger |n_1 n_2...\rangle = (-1)^{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell-1}n_j}|n_1 n_2 ... n_\ell+1 ...\rangle.$$